# XXXX does not have a naming container... asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, data-binding

I am working with a 3rd party datagrid (Janus Grid for ASP.Net) and I have the following exception caused when trying to bind the control to my data source:

> The GridEXDropDown control
>   'grdLocationHistorydd0' does not have
>   a naming container.  Ensure that the
>   control is added to the page before
>   calling DataBind.

The Janus grid is a bit weird - basically the main grid is bound to a data source which all works fine, unfortunely the problem occurs when one of the embedded grids (within the main grid) is bound to a data source and this is completely beyond me.

Any ideas about the main cause of this error or simply a few ideas about debuggin the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the grid dynamically you might need to first add a control that implements INamingContainer and then add the grid within that control.